# Post to server NSMutableArray with dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hello I filled a `NSMutableArray` with dictionaries, and I need send by post to server ( I am using `AFNetworking`),  but I get `<null>` response, How I post a array to get a OK response? below I show the code:

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"contacts":array};
 AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"https://www.angelpolitics.com"]];

[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"/mobile/ios_contact.php"
                                                  parameters:dict
                                ];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {



    if (JSON !=nil) {

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        NSLog(@"Result contacts %@",JSON);


        if ([[JSON objectForKey:@"a"]isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {


            UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notification" message:@"Leads add succesfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alertView show];

            [self.delegate dismissController:self];


            NSLog(@"Resulta AddLeads %@",JSON);
        }





    }else{


        UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Data do not send try again, please" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertView show];



    }



} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", [error description]);

}];

operation.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/json",@"text/html", nil];




[queue addOperation:operation];
```

And the array is the follow:

```
(
        {
        email = "N/A";
        lastname = Doe;
        name = John;
        phone = "(555) 555-55";
    },
        {
        email = "N/A";
        lastname = Poppins;
        name = Mary;
        phone = "(333) 333-333";
    },
        {
        email = "N/A";
        lastname = Skywalker;
        name = Luke;
        phone = "(222) 222-2222";
    }
)
```

Comment: what code does the server return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now much easier with `AFNetworking` 2.0 (you will have to download and integrate the framework again):

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"contacts":array};
NSString * urlString = @"https://www.angelpolitics.com/mobile/ios_contact.php";
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] POST:urlString parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"response : %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

And mostly, it depends on the web developer, on how he developes the web service and how is he expecting the data to arrive in.

Comment: And how he is handling the success, it wouldn't be the first web developer to return an invalid JSON response resulting in a failing JSON parser.

Comment: then that is beyond him, and a talk with the web developer wouldn't hurt

Comment: I talked with web developer and both are trying fix the problem, but my question is :How I send the array into the dictionary well?because the backend developer told me that  received "(" instead of "["

Comment: `NSDictionary *dict=@{@"contacts":array};` this is setting and array in a dictionary. for the key "contacts"